# c# Calling method in partial call from another class

Tags: c#, listview, partial-classes

I'm making c# app where I need to access method in partial class from another class.

To be more specific I want to add items to listview from class that is different from partial class but in same namespace.

I tried like this:

```
    public partial class Aa : Form
{
    public static void UpdateListView(string[] array)
    {
        if (ProcessNetUsageList.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ProcessNetUsageList.Invoke(new Action<string[]>(UpdateListView), array);
        }
        else
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(array[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
                item.SubItems.Add(array[i]);
            ProcessNetUsageList.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

and then access it from another class like:

```
class Test
{
    test()
    {
        ProgramName.Aa.UpdateListView(someArray);
    }
}
```

But its giving an error because static method can only access static variables,and my listview isnt static(i created that listview in vs designer).

If i remove static keyword from method in partial class then i cant access it.I tried to create instance of partial class but without success.Any idea is welcome

**note**:Im using Invoke in my UpdateListView method because later that will be running on new thread

Comment: `"I tried to create instance of partial class but without success."` - Well, what did you try?  Because to access an instance of an object you would indeed need an instance of that object.  So where is the instance of your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of an object-oriented language is that objects don't have universal access to modify other objects. This is a *good thing*.

You've provided relatively little code so it's hard to provide a perfect answer here, but there are a few paradigms that resolve this issue.

One is to pass the instance to your test class, like this:

```
class Test
{
    test(ProgramName.Aa form)
    {
        form.UpdateListView(someArray);
    }
}
```

Or, if class `test` actually contains the `ListView`, you can pass that to a static method in `Aa`.

```
class Test
{
    ListView someListView;
    test()
    {
        ProgramName.Aa.UpdateListView(someListView, someArray);
    }
}
```

Ultimately, you should think about the logical relationship between these objects to determine how these objects should communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static keyword from UpdateListView, as you have done before. In test(), you need to instantiate Aa before you access UpdateListView.

```
Aa temp = new Aa()
```

You can then access the method by using

```
temp.UpdateListView(someArray);
```

Comment: I did try that too,but it gives me "Embedded statement cannon be a declaration or labeled statement"

Comment: your answer is misleading, because simply creating a new object of type `Aa` will result in an empty object. This will not be the same as in the example. With it's own (probably empty) ListView